# How to select identical meshes from a single imported model, in object mode, that are separated individually in the outliner?

Tags: selection-tools, object-mode

I have this castle model I received from a CG website and it came in the form of an .obj. After importing I noticed that almost every piece was separated from one another. I was hoping to find help in selecting all the pieces that are the same (even though they are separated in the outliner). They also do not have unique materials and have semi-unique names.[image][image]

Comment: If Shift L doesn't work it means that the meshes of the objects are not linked, if you want to link them, select all the object, shift select the one you want to link to, then Ctrl L > Link Object Data

Answer (score 1):

If they all use the same material, you should be able to use *Select Linked* to select all the objects.

<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>L</kbd>, or in the top left of the 3d viewport click on *Select* for a dropdown and go to *Select Linked*.